# JPA Transaction Isolation & Locking

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have a following service which is part of a web app which receives multiple concurrent requests.

```
@Service 
@Transactional 
public class PlantService { 

private final PlantRepository plantRepository;

public void update(String name,int count) {

    var plant = plantRepository.findByName(name);

    plant.setCount(count);

    plantRepository.save(plant); 

    callSomeExternalAPI();
}

// ...
}
```

**When does target row get locked ? At the beginning of transaction or when save is called ?**

If row gets locked at the beginning of transaction how does **Optimistic Locking** work with **@Transactional** ?

How is it possible to get a version mismatch when row is locked by transaction? Does locking make it pessimistic ?

Does that mean that we can't use Optimistic locking with @Transactional or do we need to change Isolation    Level ?

**When is lock on updated row getting released?**

Consider following situation :

```
      Thread 1 calls update.

      Thread 2 calls update at the same time.
```

Is Thread 2 getting blocked until  transaction is done which means that it has to wait until **callSomeExternalAPI()** is executed ?

If that's a case how should I prevent blocking? Can I use some other Isolation Level ?

Comment: What type of lock are you talking about - optimistic locking is different from DB row/table locks, so you might be confusing things. You use optimistic locking to avoid locking rows in the DB upfront, optimistic in the assumption that there won't be a conflict, and if one does exist, you can detect it and retry 'this' operation. Optimistic locking is more a mechanism to detect when something changes out from under you. Pessimistic locking prevents others from making changes - it would need to be on the first read (select for update) so that other transactions cannot modify it.

Comment: If you code out your hypothetical situation, you should be able to tell what happens. I'd expect that they aren't both exactly the same time. Both will try to update the row, and both will use a version check with a value from the time they read in the entity - this will mean that the second to update will wait for the first's transaction to complete, the statement will get issued and there will be no rows updated - which forces your JPA provider to throw an optimistic lock exceptions to let you know the row was modified.